# Inferring correct types of lambdas in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

Why can't the compiler infer the types of `x` and `y` correctly?
I've read some articles about Scala's type inference but still can't figure out why it is impossible.

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
        val f = (x,y) => add(y,x) // error: missing parameter type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `add` may be overloaded with other types and thus implementing it to even handle simple cases like yours would add a lot of complexity to the compiler.

**edit**:

You may know, that haskell is able to infer the types of such a declaration, but that is only due to the fact, that haskell does not support overloading.

Comment: Could be, because the compiler sees, that it actually is a pass through and therefore the same as `val f = add _` and as this is already implemented it is handled like that, just guessing though.